# jQuery Sortable Lists with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am attempting to make a sortable list out of list items populated from the database using the jQuery plug in but the effect is only applied to the first item presented:

```
<?php if(isset($bookmarks)) : foreach($bookmarks as $row) :?>
    <div id="makeDrag">

    <?php $fixed = preg_replace('#^[^:/.]*[:/]+#i', '', $row->URL); ?>

    <li>
        <div class="well">
            <div><?php echo anchor('http://'.$fixed, $row->Name); ?></div>
            <div><strong>Comments:</strong> <?php echo $row->Comments; ?></div>
            <h4 class="btn-small">
                <?php echo anchor("site/delete/$row->id", "Delete"); ?>
            </h4>
        </li>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I can kind of see where this is going wrong but do not know how to fix it. I would obviously like the effect to affect all the populated `li` not just the first one. Any help would be great. Sorry if I am unclear, I can try and rephrase things if this is confusing.

Comment: Can you please post the jQuery code you're using. Also, your closing `div` and `li` are the wrong way round, you have no `ul` or `ol` to contain your `li` and it is invalid to use a block level `div` inside an inline `li`.

Comment: I was able to make this work by switching around some of the tags. I am curious how I can achieve the same effect without using the block-level div.

Comment: Use a `span` set to `display: block;` in CSS

Comment: hi Julian25, can you write your own answer to your question so that this question doesn't appear as unanswered anymore? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cause is likely because you have

```
$('#makeDrag').sortable();
```

but you also have a foreach statement that creates multiple `#makeDrag` elements thus making your HTML invalid.

To fix this:

```
<?php if(isset($bookmarks)) : ?>
    <ul id="makeDrag">
    <?php foreach($bookmarks as $row) : ?>
        <?php $fixed = preg_replace('#^[^:/.]*[:/]+#i', '', $row->URL); ?>
        <li>
            <div class="well">
                <div><?php echo anchor('http://'.$fixed, $row->Name); ?></div>
                <div><strong>Comments:</strong> <?php echo $row->Comments; ?></div>
                <h4 class="btn-small"><?php echo anchor("site/delete/$row->id", "Delete"); ?></h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

HTH